# rails download file from public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

In my local, I have written

```
   <%= link_to 'App', "/App.apk", data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```

It is working fine
simply downloading App.apk file which is present in public folder

But on production, the same link gives the error

```
 Not Found

 The requested URL /App.apk/ was not found on this server.
```

Can anyone give me any idea why this is behaving differently
on different environment

Thankyou in advance

Comment: You should add this line `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `app/config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it didn't worked

Comment: @Anjalikhant Plz check my answer, does that work for you ?

Comment: Yes sure 
please give me half an hour, I am in between of other work

Comment: Did you check in the server, if the file is present in the public directory ? Can you check `File.exist?("#{Rails.root}/public/app.apk")`

Comment: Yes, the file is present there. The issue is resolved .thankyou so much for your response

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of adding path in direct link, create one action which download the file from public folder.

routes.rb

```
get 'download_apk'
```

in your controller add below action which downloads apk file

```
def download_apk
  send_file("#{Rails.root}/public/App.apk")
end
```